# Send multiple embedded images from outlook using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

Following is the code which sends single embedded image very fine from Outlook using c#

```
public void sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK()
{
    try
    {
       Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

        Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        string imageCid = "image001.jpg@123";
        oMsg.HTMLBody = String.Format("<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>", imageCid);
        Attachment attachment1 = oMsg.Attachments.Add(@"E:\wallpapers\WRLDMAP.jpg", OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "img");
        attachment1.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid);

                       //Add an attachment.
        String sDisplayName = "MyAttachment";
        int iPosition = (int)oMsg.HTMLBody.Length + 1;
        int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
        //now attached the file

        Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add(@"C:\\SampleFile.txt", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);

        //Subject line
        oMsg.Subject = "Your Subject will go here.";
        // Add a recipient.
        Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
        Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("abc8@in.com");
        oRecip.Resolve();

        oMsg.Send();
        oRecip = null;
        oRecips = null;
        oMsg = null;
        oApp = null;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {   }
}
```

I dont know how to send multiple embedded images.
What modifications are required in the above code?

Comment: Why are you using Outlook to send emails? Why aren't you using SMTP?

Comment: Its the need of my application.

Comment: How is it a need of your application to open Outlook to send an email? Use SMTP.

Comment: i m developing an outlook plugin

Comment: What plugin architecture are you using. You should not need to be instanciating a new `Outlook.Application`.